# Find all prime numbers $n$ such that $n$, $n + 10$ and $n + 14$ are all prime numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

By inspection, I think $n=3$ is the solution to this problem.  Because $n+10=13$ and $n+14=17$ are both primes. I just have no idea how to prove that there is no other solution ( or there is? ).

Comment: Hint: Every prime number $p \geq 5$ is in one of the forms $6k - 1$ or $6k + 1$.

Comment: @AbuNussa FYI, a fairly recent, quite similar question, is [Proof verification: $p, p + 4, p + 14$ are primes. Find $p$.](/q/4520933).

Comment: thanks for hint and reference they are so helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $n,n+10,n+14$ are all different $\mod 3$. If you need more:

> So one of them must be a multiple of $3$, and if they are all prime, then one must in fact be $3$. It can't be the latter two.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a hint, rather a full solution.

Comment: I would just say "HINT: 3..."

Comment: wow. . that is a full solution!  thank you very much